# Brightness slider not working

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, dell-inspiron

I have installed `Windows 8.1`. I am unable to change brightness, I found the brightness slider in `Windows mobility center` but this simply does not work. I move the slider but brightness does not change. I am using `Dell Inspiron 3521`

Comment: Check your graphics driver. Is it installed properly? Or Download and Install latest Graphics Driver from Dell's Website.

Comment: This behavior is normally controlled by OEM drivers.  Are those drivers marked as supporting Windows 8.1 specifically?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of things you need to check with this particular model of laptop:

1)Go into your BIOS settings, go to advanced > function key behaviour and check that function keys are set to multimedia.  I know this controls the fn+F4/F5 behaviour, but I have just seen a couple of posts saying that this fixed it and the two are somehow linked?!

2)Update drivers - Chipset, graphics, bios.  Don't use the OEM drivers - from the dell website.

3)Update drivers (again) - graphics - through control panel > device manager > graphics card > right click & update driver.  This will search windows update for an up to date graphics driver with full 8.1 support.

4)Change your computers power performance plan to "high performance".  I've just seen a post on a forum saying that this was a problem and when the power plan changed, the controls came back to life.